# how to pass a function as an argument value in jdbc preparedStatement, CallableStatement or Spring-jdbc StoredProcedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using **Spring Jdbc** to perform some **stored procedures** calls using the **StoredProcedure** class.

Some of the procedures are taking a date as an input parameter.
*(I can't change the procedures: they are outside my project)*

In my business logic, I have some rules about date:
in some case, for the same proc, I can have to provide an arbitrary date OR the current system date of the database (the ORACLE sysdate keyword)

How should I provide this kind of parameter when calling the proc ?
If I pass "sysdate", spring and jdbc resolve that as a VARCHAR type and the call fails.

I don't want to call the db for retrieving the sysdate first as I have seen in some documentation.

More generally, how should I do that when using all flavor of JDBC using '?' as a placeholder for sql query arguments ?
I've spend some time trying to find a way to doing this, but I did not manage to find an answer.

Test DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "AAATEST" ("A_TEXT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), "A_DATE" DATE, "A_NUMBER" NUMBER) ;

create or replace PROCEDURE TEST_PROC ( someText in VARCHAR2, someNumber in NUMERIC, someDate in date) IS
BEGIN
    insert into AAATEST(a_text, a_number, a_date) values (someText, someNumber, someDate);
END;
```

Test class in Java:

```
public class Test {
  public static class MyStoredProc extends StoredProcedure {
    protected MyStoredProc(DataSource ds) {
      super(ds, "test_proc");
      declareParameter(new SqlParameter("someText", Types.VARCHAR));
      declareParameter(new SqlParameter("someNumber", Types.NUMERIC));
      declareParameter(new SqlParameter("someDate", Types.DATE));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource("driver", "url", "username","password",false);
    MyStoredProc myStoredProc = new MyStoredProc(ds);

    //this one is ok
    myStoredProc.execute(new HashMap(){{
      put("someText", "hello world");
      put("someNumber", 3.14);
      put("someDate", new Date());
    }});

    //this one fails with 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:140)'
    myStoredProc.execute(new HashMap(){{
      put("someText", "abc");
      put("someNumber", 123);
      put("someDate", "sysdate");
    }});            
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `StoredProcedure` (or the `RdbmsOperation` hierarchy in general) are going to help you here. Their logic around the generation of the call string is not written in such a way as to allow extension and customisation.

My suggestion would be to abandon the `StoredProcedure` and use `JdbcTemplate` directly. It's a bit more of a faff, but you get full control over the call string.  Then, when you need to call your procedure with `sysdate`, you can just: add it to the call string, e.g.

```
{call TEST_PROC(?, ?, sysdate)}
```

You'd need to dynamically decide whther to use the call string with the `sysdate`, or one without, and decide which parameters to add accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately it is looking sadely true... I've wasted some time trying to create some extended SimpleJdbcCall class that will change the '?' to the wanted function expr. But now the CallableStatementCreatorFactory is crashing while preparing the parameters map for db execution...
With some more time wasted I will be able to fix that... but it will be a lot of mess...
I was trying to convert my boss and team to use spring-jdbc to avoid our current raw sql messy soup. 
Not sure this will be playing in the favor of Spring...